# VS Code own Language Extension for a specific file name

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to make an extension that adds support for a new language to vs code. I have already made it work for all files with the extension ".txt".

But I want to do it for logfiles. These have the following structure:

`something.log.timestamp.txt` -> **example**: `something.log.20230509_131031.txt`

How can I make that all files with the structure are recognized as this language?

Here is an excerpt from the package.json:

```
"contributes": {
    "languages": [{
      "id": "mylang",
      "aliases": ["MyLang", "mylang"],
      "extensions": [".txt"],
      "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }],
    "grammars": [{
      "language": "mylang",
      "scopeName": ".txt",
      "path": "./syntaxes/mylang.tmLanguage.json"
    }]
  },
```

I tried to apply regex but it did not work for me.

Comment: assign the languageID `mylang` to files with the `files.association` setting

Comment: any chance you'll consider changing the filename format to `something.<timestamp>.log.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rioV8 for the comment.

I have added the following function to my extension:

```
function updateFileAssociations() {
    const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
    const fileAssociations: { [key: string]: string } = configuration.get('files.associations') || {};
  
    fileAssociations['something.log.*.txt'] = 'mylang';
  
    configuration.update('files.associations', fileAssociations, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
}
```